# Electron failed to load resource

Tags: webpack, electron, content-security-policy

i using https://github.com/pbarbiero/basic-electron-react-boilerplate but after update on my macOS i can't load anymore my application.

On inspector, this error is show:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content
>   Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the
>   'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-Z+HxFhVCHMznEI/lLsU2FT9krRiVCTm6bGApEd5HAtk='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that
>   'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
>   fallback.
>
> index.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I tried this technique https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#csp-http-header but got same error.

My macOS version is Mojave 10.14.2 (18C54)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and I think I found a fix for it. As the warning message suggests, inline-scripts are blocked because they violate the Content Security Policy (CSP).

The CSP is defined in www/index.html: "meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" ...."

Changing

script-src * data: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval';
in the content-string to

script-src * data: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';

fixed it for me.

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#Unsafe_inline_script

Comment: Hi Muhammad Amir, thanks for the answer. But this error occurred on webpack-dev-server and i do not have a file index.html for modify. I guess is webpack error, i don't know. Your error is on the wepback-dev-server too?

Comment: Can you try to add this to your electron window options:
webPreferences: {
      zoomFactor: 1,
      allowRunningInsecureContent: true,
      nodeIntegration: true,
    }

Comment: Please, can you show your main.development.js file?

Comment: As a last resort, remove the indexPath variable, and directly specify the path of index file like this:
mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app.html`);
And make sure that the path is correct!

Comment: Nothing =((, i try to:

new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      'meta': {
        'Content-Security-Policy': { 'http-equiv': 'Content-Security-Policy', 'content': "script-src * data: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';" },        
      }
    }),

but nothing yet

Comment: Leidson Cruz, Did you change main.loadURL?

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  'meta': {
    'Content-Security-Policy': { 'http-equiv': 'Content-Security-Policy', 'content': "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'self'" },
  }
}),
```

Comment: your answer is not very explicative, which file is it ? where did you put that code ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case Content-Security-Policy is found in electron/src/setup.js

```js
function setupContentSecurityPolicy(customScheme) {
  electron_2.session.defaultSession.webRequest.onHeadersReceived((details, callback) => {
    callback({
      responseHeaders: Object.assign(Object.assign({}, details.responseHeaders), {
        'Content-Security-Policy': [
          // electron_is_dev_1.default
          //     ? `default-src ${customScheme}://* 'unsafe-inline' devtools://* 'unsafe-eval' data:`
          //     : `default-src ${customScheme}://* 'unsafe-inline' data:`,
        ]
      }),
    });
  });
}
```

I have removed it has worked but it is not safe more details[electron security docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security)